# Min distance between two addresses in list

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, geolocation

I have two dataframes with the following columns AccountNumber, Latitude_Radians, Long_Radians

dataframe1: xs contains only customers without cell phones
dataframe2: ys contains all customers with cell phones.

Im trying to iterate through each Account in xs to find the closest (distance) from an account in ys.

This will help me determine if we would have cell signal at a person who doesnt have a cell phone.

Im here but getting an error...

```py
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2

def mydistanceCheck(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2):
    R = 6373.0
    
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = (sin(dlat/2))**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1.0-a))
    distance = R * c
    return distance


distarr = []
for n in xs.index:
    minDist = None
    point = None
    for p in ys.index:
        #DISTANCE CHECK HERE - 
        #check = mydistanceCheck(xs.Latitude, ys.Latitude, xs.Longitude, ys.Longitude)
        check = mydistanceCheck(xs.lat_radians, ys.lat_radians, xs.Long_radians, ys.Long_radians)
        if not minDist:
            minDist = check
            point = p
    else:
        if check < minDist:
                minDist = check
                point = p
    distarr.append({'min': minDist, 'to': point, 'from': n})
    
print("{}".format(distarr))
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\***8981.py in <module>
     19         #DISTANCE CHECK HERE -
     20         #check = mydistanceCheck(xs.Latitude, ys.Latitude, xs.Longitude, ys.Longitude)
---> 21         check = mydistanceCheck(xs.lat_radians, ys.lat_radians, xs.Long_radians, ys.Long_radians)
     22         if not minDist:
     23             minDist = check

C:\Users\***8981.py in mydistanceCheck(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2)
      6     dlon = lon2 - lon1
      7     dlat = lat2 - lat1
----> 8     a = (sin(dlat/2))**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))**2
      9     c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1.0-a))
     10     distance = R * c

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
    183         if len(self) == 1:
    184             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 185         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    186 
    187     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the shown code. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Sorry new to pasting code, didnt realize it didnt format correctly

Comment: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>` tells you that you are using `mydistanceCheck` with series (`xs.lat_radians`, `ys.lat_radians`, ...) instead of floats. `sin` from `math` can't deal with series.